# substring / extract expected from string value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i have below text and taking filename from below text. but need date extract as well. but instead of hard coded i want as substring function where i can extract date from the text itself.

```
select 
SUBSTR(fname, INSTR(fname, '_', -1)+1) as fname,  
'20181217' as fdate 
from
(
   select '/home/dir/file_name_20181217_product.csv' as fname from dual
);
```

Comment: You'll need to define a pattern that you can use - it looks like you have an 8-digit 'date', everything from the last slash up to that is the file name, for instance. And then look at the `regexp_substr` function, maybe? You can only stick with plain `substr` if the file name has a fixed number of underscores in those positions, really; which may be the case for your real names, of course...

Comment: sorry for confusion, i have edited the date output. i need exact same date what comes in the text from substring instring command

Comment: You are using technical terms for things that are different from their standard definition. In a field like computer technology, that may create problems. In your example, the entire substring `file_name_20181217_product.csv` is the filename. Your current code extracts just `product.csv` - that is **not** the filename, at least not according to the standard technical definition. You would do well to create a new term for what **you** need, so as not to cause confusion, both for yourself and for others who may work on the same task, now or in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that date always occurs before the first underscore( where your "fname" starts), and it's of 8 digits, you could do:

```
select 
SUBSTR(fname, INSTR(fname, '_', -1)+1) as fname,  
SUBSTR(fname, INSTR(fname, '_', -1)-8,8) as fdate
from
(
   select '/home/dir/file_name_20181217_product.csv' as fname from dual
);

FNAME       fdate    
----------- --------
product.csv 20181217
```

Comment: *product.csv* is not the filename..... i have already substr for filename... which is working properly.. i needed extraction of date only.... which i think no instr required. this is fixed filename so this can be extracted by TO_DATE(SUBSTR(fname, 11,8),'DDMMYYYY') as fdate

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `regexp_substr()`:

```
   replace(regexp_substr(fname, '_[0-9]{8}_', 1, 1), '_', '') as date
```

And for the filename:

```
   regexp_substr(fname, '[^_]+$', 1, 1) as fname,
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get date "as is", then this might help:

```
SQL> select
  2    SUBSTR(fname, INSTR(fname, '_', -1)+1) as fname,
  3    regexp_substr(fname, '\d+') as fdate                  --> this
  4  from (select '/home/dir/file_name_20181217_product.csv' as fname from dual);

FNAME       FDATE
----------- --------
product.csv 20181217

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select 
SUBSTR(fname, INSTR(fname, '/',1,3)+1),
instr(fname,'_')-INSTR(fname, '/',1,3)+1)) as fname,  
to_date(substr(fname,instr(fname,'_',1)+1,8),YYYYMMDD) as fdate 
from
(
   select '/home/dir/file_name_20181217_product.csv' as fname from dual
);
```